# How to structure Google OR-Tools MPSolver to assign multiple tasks per worker?

Tags: or-tools

I'm following the MPSolver java examples in an attempt to assign two tasks per worker.  A worker must perform two tasks or no tasks, a task can be assigned to only one worker.  A matrix indicates the tasks that a worker can perform.  The goal is to maximize the number of worker-task combinations.  Some workers and tasks may not get assigned.  The examples cover single worker-task assignments, but I don't follow how to structure MPSolver constraints to associate two tasks per worker.

Subsequently, I need to minimize the amount of time each worker spends.  The time worked is associated with individual workers.

Comment: Discussed here: https://github.com/google/or-tools/discussions/3130